# How can I get the x/y location of a touch relative to the entire view when I touch a button?

Tags: android, touch, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I would like the touch information relative to the entire screen, but I'm getting touch info just relative to the button.

```
ButtonTouchListener = new OnTouchListener(){

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.somebutton
                          //do things
                    //....etc
            }

           int action = event.getAction();
       switch(action){
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
         act += event.toString();
         System.out.println("release: " + act);
}};
```

The x and y I'm getting from the event relates to the button (0, 0 is the corner of the button, not the corner of the screen). How can I get the x and y locations relative to the entire screen ONLY when a button is pressed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the touch position relative to the view add the touch event's (x,y) to your button's (x,y); to get the button's position relative to it's parent (your view) use the `getLeft()` and `getTop()` methods.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) for `View` has the following under **Position**:

> It is possible to retrieve the location of a view by invoking the
>   methods getLeft() and getTop(). The former returns the left, or X,
>   coordinate of the rectangle representing the view. The latter returns
>   the top, or Y, coordinate of the rectangle representing the view.
>   These methods both return the location of the view relative to its
>   parent. For instance, when getLeft() returns 20, that means the view
>   is located 20 pixels to the right of the left edge of its direct
>   parent.

Example code for your `onTouch` method:

```
float screenX = v.getLeft() + event.getX();   // X in Screen Coordinates
float screenY = v.getTop() + event.getY();    // Y in Screen Coordinates
```

Comment: if its inside a scroll view you can add also `+ scrollView.scrollY` or scrollX

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do it (as far as I can figure) is to invoke event.getRawX() and event.getRawY(). This works if your view is the whole screen. If not then, I don't know, you're out of luck I guess, but rawx and y work for my purpose.